# Automate publishing ArcMap mxd to ArcGIS Online using ArcGIS REST API or Python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-online

I have a mxd file that contains several feature classes and they get updated every day. I am with ArcGIS 10.1 at the moment. It would be potentially upgraded to 10.5 in the near future anyway.

I have successfully published the mxd file to ArcGIS Online as a Feature Layer using ArcMap -> Share As -> Service -> Hosted Services on ArcMap.

As the feature classes get updated every day, I would like to achieve an automated approach to allow the mxd file to be published/updated to ArcGIS Online on a daily basis. Such that the Feature Layer can be updated there accordingly.

Is this something that can be achieved using ArcGIS Python or REST API?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, though your approach should not be to republish the McD, but just update the data in the feature service. Both the python api and ArcREST do this.

Comment: 10.5 is a lot more capable than 10.1 with respect to Python and publishing, so much so that they might as well be different products. There are tons of Python samples online, but I wouldn't expect them to work with ArcGIS releases below 10.3.

Answer (score 1):

There is an arcpy function, the [arcpy.MXDToWebMap_server](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/server-toolbox/mxd-to-webmap.htm). In order to create a WebMap, I believe it also uploads the features in the server.

It appears to have been [new at ArcGIS Desktop 10.3](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/main/get-started/whats-new-in-arcgis.htm).

Comment: I believe arcpy.MXDToWebMap_server is for ArcGIS 10.1 above.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by following the instruction here:
http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/Publishing_a_map_service_with_Python/00sq000000nw000000/